# How do I get rows from a column excluding certain rows, which have Id saved in another table

Tags: sequelize.js

The 'blocked' table has two columns, 'userId', and 'messageId' which is foreign key to the table 'messages'.

I want to get the messages after filtering the blocked ones. I tried this :

```
messages.findAll({
    where: {
        userId,
    },
    include:[{
        model: 'blocked',
        required: false
        attributes:[],
        where: {
            userId,
        },
    }],
});
```

Didn't work. Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate this into two queries

```
const blocked = await blocked.findAll({
    where: {
        userId,
        attributes: ['messageId']
    }
});

const blockedIds = blocked.map(b => b.messageId);

const messages = await messages.findAll({
    where: {
        id: { $notIn: blockedIds }
    }
});
```